# MustacheJS partials not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I am trying to use a partial for a simple object with an enumerable property, but the partials won't render.

Here is a link to my [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/qtgye/skkhdrtm/).

**The object**

```
obj6    = {
           people : [
              { firstName : 'Jayson', lastName : 'Buquia', isMale : true },
              { firstName : 'Jane', lastName : 'Doe', isMale : false },
              { firstName : 'John', lastName : 'Smith', isMale : true }
            ]
          };
```

**The partials**

```
 partials = { person : '<li>{{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}{{^isMale}}, a female {{/isMale}}.</li>' }
```

**The template**

```
<ul>
  {{ #people }} 
    {{>person}}
  {{ /people }}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change `tpl = $('.template .main').html()` to `tpl = $('.template .main').text()` as `html()` wll return `<h3>Names:</h3><ul>{{ #people }} {{&gt;person}}{{ /people }}</ul>`  which is not valid template.

```
var $p     = $('#container'),
tpl     = $('.template .main').text(),           
partials = { person : '<li>{{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}{{^isMale}}, a female {{/isMale}}.</li>' },
        obj6    = {
            people : [
                { firstName : 'Jayson', lastName : 'Buquia', isMale : true },
                { firstName : 'Jane', lastName : 'Doe', isMale : false },
                { firstName : 'John', lastName : 'Smith', isMale : true }
            ]
        };

 $p.append(Mustache.render(tpl,obj6,partials));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skkhdrtm/5/)

Or convert your div to `script` tag as templete here is demo:-

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skkhdrtm/8/)

Comment: using `text()` only returns the text node, the element tags are gone.

Comment: or create script tag like http://jsfiddle.net/skkhdrtm/8/ and which is best and recomented

Comment: Using the script tag is the best approach I can use. Thanks  a lot.